# Clickable images in text

Tags: android, image, button, textview

I want to add interactive images in TextView, already trying ImageSpan and ImageGetter, but images added with them can't be pressed. Any suggestion of how i can get result like this:

[image]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ClickableSpan is what you need:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html

> If an object of this type is attached to the text of a TextView with a
>   movement method of LinkMovementMethod, the affected spans of text can
>   be selected. If clicked, the onClick(View) method will be called

.